# How do I deploy my own GPG keyserver?

Tags: gnupg

I would like to set up a read-only key-server operating by me where I am going to publish my own keys. So that anyone could do `gpg --keyserver example.mymedia.su --receive-keys 0xDEADBEEF` and get the key. Is it some sort of HTTP server? Is it enough to just put static files and serve them via Apache? If so, in which directories they should be located?

I do not like that I cannot make any changes of *my* key on so-called public key-server network. However, it would be nice to support a GnuPG compatible protocol to share the key.

Answer (score 0):

There are many keyserver implementations available like [Hockeypuck](https://github.com/hockeypuck/hockeypuck).

Answer (score 0):

The sequoia-pgp team built [Hagrid](https://sequoia-pgp.org/blog/2019/06/14/20190614-hagrid/) the "keeper of keys". It is written in Rust and is based on [Sequoia-pgp](https://sequoia-pgp.org/) which itself is a an OpenPGP Library.

I did not deploy an instance yet, due to lack of time, but it might be a solution to your requirements. It is already running on https://keys.openpgp.org